# Recursive set proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Let $S$ be the set of positive integers defined by
Basis Step: $5 ∈ S$.
Recursive Step: If $n ∈ S$, then $3n ∈ S$ and $n^2 ∈ S$.
Show that if $n ∈ S$, then there exists some $q ∈ Z$ such that $n = 10q + 5$.

I used a proof by induction.

Base case:
$5 ∈ S$
$$$$
for $n^2$ $$ 5 *5=(10q+5)^2$$
$$25=100q^2 + 100q+25$$
$$0=q(100q+100)$$
$$q=0,-1$$
We only care about the zero $$0∈Z$$
for $3n$
$$3(5) =3(10q+5)$$
$$15 = 30q+15$$
$$0=30q$$
$$q = 0$$
$$0∈Z$$

Inductive Hypothesis: Assume that if $k ∈ S$, then there exists some $q∈Z$ such that $k=10q+5$ such that $3k∈S$ and $k^2∈S$

Inductive Step:
for $3(k+1)$
$$3(k+1) = 3k + 3$$

By the Inductive Hypothesis
$$3(10q+5)+3$$
$$30q+ 15 + 3$$
$$30q+18$$
$$30q + 18 ∈ Z$$

for $(k+1)^2$
$$(k+1)^2=k^2+2k+1$$
By the Inductive Hypothesis
$$k^2+2k+1=(10q+5)^2 +2(10q+5)+1$$
$$100q^2+100q+25+20q+10+1$$
$$100q^2+120q+36$$
$$100q^2+120q+36 ∈ Z$$
Conclusion:
We proven that both the final results are an element of z because they are a sum of integers. Thus we have proven the claim.

My question is is my proof wrong? Thank you. Please send any feedback. Thank you.

Comment: Is the recursive step (in your first paragraph) supposed to say $n^2\in S$? It now says $n$ $2\in S$, which is probably not what you mean.

Comment: yes it is supposed to say $n^2$

Comment: I just fixed it.

Comment: Also, are you familiar with modular arithmetic?

Comment: For 3n you have $3(10q+5)=30q+15$. Now rearrange as $10q'+5$. $30q+15=10(3q)+10+5=10(3q+1)+5$.

Comment: We have not studied modular arithmetic

Answer (score 1):

I am completely lost when attempting to read this proof. Your idea to prove this by induction is fine. But I do not see the structure of a proof by induction. What you want to show is:

1. The base case: The smallest element $k\in S$ has the form $k=10q+5$ for some integer $q$. For this step to make sense you should first show that $S$ has a smallest element, and determine what it is.
2. The induction step: For every $N\in S$, if every $k\in S$ with $k<N$ is of the form $k=10q+5$ for some integer $q$, then also $N=10q'+5$ for some integer $q'$.

Then you can conclude that every element $k\in S$ is of the form $k=10q+5$.

---

Alternatively, you can prove the claim by induction on the recursion depth:

1. The base case: Every number at the $0$-th recursion step is of the form $10q+5$. Of course the only number at the $0$-th recursion step is $5$.
2. The induction step: If every number at the $k$-th recursion step is of the form $10q+5$, then every number at the $k+1$-th recursion step is of the form $10q+5$. More explicitly: You want to show that *if* $n\in S$ and $n=10q+5$ for some integer $q$, *then* also $3n$ and $n^2$ are of the form $10q+5$ for some integer $q$.

Then you can conclude that every element of the recursively defined set $S$ is of the form $10q+5$.

Comment: An alternative (essentially the same as induction by recursive depth but formulated differently) is define $S_0=\{5\}$ and $S_{i+1}=\{3n|n \in S_i\}\cup\{n^2|n \in S_i\}$. Then $S=S_0 \cup S_1 \cup ...$ and you can do it by induction on the $S_i$.

Comment: @roundsquare, exactly, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your proof is that you don't actually prove that $n = 10q + 5$ for a $q\in Z$, but that the numbers are in Z, which is always true since the $q\in Z$.

**Solution:**

If $5 \in S$ then $5=10q+5 \implies q=0 \in Z$

We suppose that $k \in S$ and there is a $q' \in Z$ so that $k=10q' +5$.

We have to show that for a $k+z$ there is a $q'' \in Z$ so that $k+z=10q'' + 5$ (Note here that the $k+1$ is not the next number in $S$ because $6\notin S$). We know that $z$ is a positive integer so.

$10q' +5 + z = 10q'' + 5 \implies  z = (q'' -q)10$.

So $10|z$.

$10q'+5 + z = 10q'' + 5 \implies q' + \frac{z}{10} = q''$.

$\frac{z}{10} \in Z$ and $q' \in Z$.

So $q'' \in Z$

To conclude, if $n \in S$ then there is a $q \in Z$ so that $n = 10q + 5$

Answer (score 0):

You need to prove that $S \subseteq T=10\mathbb N + 5$.

By definition, every element of $S$ is either $5$ or of the form $3n$ or $n^2$ for $n \in S$.

Therefore, just prove that $5 \in T$, $3(10q+5)\in T$, and $(10q+5)^2 \in T$.

If you want to be more formal, consider this.
The elements of $S$ have *birthdates*: the first time they appear when applying the rules $$
5 \in S,
\quad n \in S \implies 3n \in S,
\quad n \in S \implies n^2 \in S
$$
Thus, $5$ is born on day $0$; $15$ and $25$ on day $1$; $45,75,225,625$ on day $2$, etc.

Use induction on birthdates.